# How to get image of a character without the borders

Tags: image, pygame, edit

I was wondering if there was application to help me get the image without its border.

For example the image

[image]

Has black background, I was wondering if there was a way to edit the black background out and only get the character .

I want to place the character image on this background

[image]

I am using pygame for that :

```
bg = pygame.image.load('images/stonetile.bmp')

image = pygame.image.load('images/human.bmp')

screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

screen.blit(image,player)
```

This what I get:

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

i think there's many ways to make this image without background the one i use is
to import it to Photoshop and use the auto select tool than the select the color you want to remove or the char you want to live than will remove the background , be sure when you do is to export your image as png and i hope this will help you

Comment: The character image was png but I converted it to bmp , You are talking about  Adobe Photoshop , meaning if  I  select the black color it would get removed , but would not that make the background white.

Answer (score 0):

Set a transparent color key with [`set_colorkey()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey).

The color key specifies the color that is treated as transparent. For example, if you have an image with a black background that should be transparent, set a black color key:

```py
image = pygame.image.load('images/human.bmp')
image .set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
```